# How to give child objects their own columns in a csv using python to export MongoDB data?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, csv, pymongo

I am very new to Python and am trying to move data from a MongoDB collection into a CSV document (needs to be done with Python, not mongoexport, if possible).

I am using the Pymongo and CSV packages to bring the data from the database, into the CSV.

This is the structure of the data I am querying from MongoDB:

Primary identifer - **Computer Name** (parent): R2D2

Details - **Computer Details** (parent): **Operating System** (Child), **Owner** (Child)

I need for **Operating System** and **Owner** to have their own columns in the CSV sheet, but they keep on falling under a single column called **Computer Name**.

Is there away around this, so that the child objects can have their own columns, instead of being grouped under their parent object?

Comment: Please can you post an example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this kind of thing many times. You will have a loop iterating your mongo query with pymongo. At the bottom end of the loop you will use the csv module to write each line of the csv file. Your question relates to what goes on in the middle of the loop.

MongoDB syntax is closest to the Java language which also fits with the 'associative array' objects in Mongo being JSON. Pymongo brings these things closer to Python types.

So the parent object will come straight from the pymongo iterable which if they have children, will by Python dictionaries:

```
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(ipaddress, port)
db = client.MyDatabase
collection = db.mycollection   

f = open('output_file.csv', 'wb')
csvwriter = csv.writer(f) 

for doc in collection.find():
    computer_name = doc.get('Computer Name')
    operating_system = computer_name.get('Operating System')
    owner = computer_name.get('owner')
    csvwriter.writerow([operating_system, owner])
f.close()
```

Of course there's probably a bunch of other columns in there without children that also come direct from the doc.